# Information on Server Is Not Updated

Tags: java, ajax, httpclient, htmlunit

I've been testing HtmlUnit with a few sites; in all these sites,they have
elements such as a radio button or checkbox that when you click, then your
profile on that site is updated; you don't need to submit a form or
anything.  But when I take the exact same actions with HtmlUnit, my profile
on the server is not really updated.  Do I have to do something special
such as synchronizing the local copy of the page that HtmlUnit has with the
server so that the server sees the change?  As an example, I have added my
code for switching my resume on a website from private/public and vice
versa.  When I visit the page on a browser, all I have to do is click one
of the two radio buttons to make the resume public/private; but when I do
the same on HtmlUnit, and then go and visit the page on a browser to check,  I can see that the information on the server hasn't been changed.  I've
included my code below.  Note that I have another method which logs in to
the site, and I know that I login correctly.  Given this is happening
with my sites for me, I thought maybe there is something like synchronizing with the server that I'm not doing.

=====================================

```
    public void update(String urlOfThePage)
    {
        // First, declare any element name or xapth that you are going to
use.        String xpathOfIsPublicRadioButton = "//input[@id='privacy_show']";
        String xpathOfIsPrivateRadioButton = "//input[@id='privacy_hide']";

        // Get the first page
        try
        {
            final HtmlPage resumePage = (HtmlPage) webclient.getPage(urlOfThePage);
            CrawlerUtility.savePage(resumePage, "resumePage");
            final HtmlRadioButtonInput makePublicRadioButton  =
(HtmlRadioButtonInput)

resumePage.getFirstByXPath(xpathOfIsPublicRadioButton);
            final HtmlRadioButtonInput makePrivateRadioButton  =
                                       (HtmlRadioButtonInput)
resumePage.getFirstByXPath(xpathOfIsPrivateRadioButton);
            Page result = null;
            if (isProfilePublic())
            {
                result = makePrivateRadioButton.click();
                System.out.println("The Profile is changed to private
now.");
                Thread.sleep(60000);
            }
            else
            {
                result = makePublicRadioButton.click();
                System.out.println("The Profile is changed to public now.");
                Thread.sleep(60000);
            }

        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }//End of try/catch block.


    }//End of update().
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't submit a form, then you may be using AJAX behind the scenes to send data to the server. HTML unit won't send the same to the server since it will not process the AJAX requests. What you need is something more sophisticated such as Sikuli http://www.sikuli.org which actually clicks on elements on your webpage in the exact same way a user does. You can also try Selenium (http://www.seleniumhq.org/) which is specific to web browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  As far as I know, HtmlUnit is supposed to execute JavaScript and Ajax just as a browser does.  So, Ajax requests are supposed to be sent.  Now, if JavaScript runs into an error and is not executed correctly, that's would explain the problem.  But with respect to Sikuli, I doubt it is more sophisticated than HtmlUnit.

Comment: Sikuli and HTMLunit are very different things. Sikuli is partof an MIT research that uses computational vision to search for elements on screen to click and simulate user input. Therefore there is no browser emulation. You are actually running the actual browser.